# Lightningchart js - range selection

Tags: javascript, selection, lightningchart

I would like to be able to select a range or an area  (circle, rectangle and lasso) on a scatter chart and be able to drag it.Once the dragging (of area selected is stopped) is stopped then calculations on the selection to be made.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have seen this question ([rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67805083/17759595) and also seen the cytometry example with the polgon. I like to select by drawing on the plot and be able to drag.

Comment: @mahmoud-mohamed-ramadan, I am asking in the context of the lightningJs chart and please try not to plug you paid content.